# which statement is better to use in provider in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-provider

I have a created a demo learning provider

here I have a simple code to delete note using provider,

here I just want to know difference between these two statements...I am getting result with these both statement..so is there any difference

here is my code

```
 IconButton(
                      onPressed: () {
                        noteprovider.deletenote(noteprovider.notelist[index]);
                        //which one of these two statement is proper and what does it differ?
                        context.read<NoteProvider>().deletenote(noteprovider.notelist[index]);
                      },
                      icon: Icon(Icons.delete),
                    )
```

Comment: As much as I know context.read<T>(...) or `Provider.of`

Answer (score 0):

**context.read** is not allowed inside the build because it is very dangerous to use there, and there are much better solutions available.

`Provider.of` is allowed in the build for backward compatibility.

Overall, the reasoning behind why `context.read` is not allowed inside building as explained in its documentation: https://pub.dev/documentation/provider/latest/provider/ReadContext/read.html